# Two kinds of subplots: two colorbars needed

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, subplot

I have a following situation: I have 12 subplots, which can be divided into two groups. The first group (8 subplots, all of uniform scale) has 'jet' colorbar, while the second one (4 subplots) has 'Rd_Bu_r' colorbar. I have to make two general colorbars but I only can understand how to make one of them (see the picture). Is there any way to make the two colorbars in the right part of the figure?
Here is what I do:

```
fig, axs= plt.subplots(4,3)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, right=0.8, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
plt.subplot(431)
  ... #(and all of them, I do it with 3 loops, for each column)
im=plt.gca().get_children()[0]
cax= fig.add_axes([0.85,0.1,0.03,0.8])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, label='RATIO')
```

[image]